# Instruments do not take snapshot on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

Using `Instruments` to analyze `memory leaks`, but the `Instruments` do not take `snapshot`, I have checked the `Automatic Anapshotting` before record.

The `Instruments` did not take anapshot:

The normal state is like this below image（download form google）:

[image: the normal state]

Comment: You're quite right that it doesn't look like the downloaded image, but _none_ of it does. It doesn't look like the app ever really got going.

Comment: @matt But you can see the Allocations is running, and my simulator is running too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transfer form memory solve this issue.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The result is below, it works:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>